# if i clone an element, when i customize (css) that element how can customize also the element cloned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If i clone an element, then if i want to customize that element (by `id`) how can customize also the element cloned ?

What i tried:

```
<div id="A"> //the element that will be clone
</div>

<div id="box" style="margin-top: 50px">  //into this box
</div>
```

CSS

```
#A{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

JS

```
$('#A').clone(true).appendTo('#box');
$('#A').css('background','#ff0000'); 

//i want to get red background also to element cloned, infact only the true original element change color :/
```

This is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t90ptkcz/1/

I hope that this is possible and you can help me. Thanks a lot and sorry for my english :)

Comment: change order of your jquery lines. First apply css then do clone.

Comment: You will need to change the `id` attribute of the cloned element as id must be unique within a document. If you want to group elements together, use a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ID # selector`  finds the unique single element from DOM though multiple elements having same ID present in DOM but `class . selector` used to get group of elements,having the same class name

```
<div id="A" class="someClass" > //the element that will be clone
 </div>

 <div id="box" style="margin-top: 50px">  //into this box
 </div>
```

JS

```
 $('#A').clone(true).appendTo('#box');
 $('.someClass').css('background','#ff0000');
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the answer from @shu and however I am not sure in which scenario this could be helpful it is possible to achieve exactly what you want by implementing a jQuery plugin with two methods:

- `$.fn.cloneAndRemember` - will clone an element and store both the source element and its clone (or clones) into a dictionary
- `$.fn.withClones` - will give you a jQuery object collection which includes a selected element and all its clones (retrieved from the dictionary)

The use case would then look like this:

```
$('#A').cloneAndRemember(true).appendTo('#box');
$('#A').withClones().css('background','#ff0000');
```